# Como fazer upload de uma imagem, porém salvá-la com o nome baseado em dados do cliente?

Tags: php, imagem

Gostaria que o usuário fizesse o upload da foto dele, porém ao salvar, gostaria que ela fosse salva com o nome igual ao CPF do cliente.

Hoje eu consigo salvar a imagem em uma pasta, mas ela vem com o nome dado pelo cliente.

PHP que salva a imagem na pasta destino que escolhi:

```php
<?php
$cpf   = $_SESSION['cpf'];

$nome_temporario=$_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
$nome_real=$_FILES["Arquivo"]["name"];
copy($nome_temporario,"imagens/$nome_real");
?>
```

HTML da página:

```html
<form action="envia_arquivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <label id="ftbt" for='arquivo'><img src="../FORM/Upload.svg"></label>
    <input name="Arquivo" id='arquivo' type='file' required accept="image/*">
    <button class="botao1" type="submit" value="Continuar">Continuar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Já procurei em tudo quanto é canto e não acho uma forma em PHP que funcione, a maioria que tentei não enviava a foto para a pasta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy($nome_temporario,"imagens/$cpf");`

Sendo `$cpf` uma variavel que voce precisa declarar e setar antes, ai esse valor pode vir de onde quiser , banco, do prorio form, da sessao etc....

Comment: da o erro: Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in *** line 6

Comment: @PedroCastilho nesse caso provavelmente o valor de `$_SESSION['cpf'];` esta vazio, verifica isso, ou se quiser testar deixa o assim `$cpf = 'testando_cpf'`

Comment: vdd... com o 'testando_cpf' foi corretamente... obrigado

Comment: aparentemente era só isso msm... a session ta vazia

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar o nome da imagem na hora de mover ela para o servidor.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES['Arquivo']['name']); //Usado para pegar a extensão da imagem

$novo_nome = $_SESSION['CPF'].".".end($temp); //concatena o a variavel do novo nome com a extensão da imagem cpf+.+extensão

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], "imagem/".$novo_nome)){
     //código caso upload tenha sucesso
 }
```

Comment: esse seu não mostrou nenhum erro, porem ao entrar na pasta, tbm não a enviou para lá

Comment: Fiz uma correção que estava faltando capturar a extensão da imagem, agora está com o mesmo código que utilizei aqui, sempre verifique o nome que ta no $_FILES e a variavel da SESSION se estão corretas.